What is the meaning of this definiton of "constitutional scholar"?
I stumbled on a definition of "constitutional scholar" on UrbanDictionary.com and I can't for the life of me understand it:

Someone who claims legal scholarship regarding the US Constitution and
who holds opinions thereof that agree with the author of the article
citing said person.
Constitutional scholars agree that <insert author's opinion here>.

I might understand what this means but everything, I feel, comes down to whether I know what "the article" means in this context. Does it simply mean "the article of the constitution" (def below) and "the author" is the person who wrote what article? In this case, this would be a wry definition, making fun of "constitutional scholars" assuming that they don't have any opinion of their own, about the Constitution and that they simply parrot what "the author" of any given "article" thereof, wrote. Also, in this case, the definition on UrbanDictionary.com could be made more clear with the use of a comma between the words "article" and "citing" in "...the author of the article citing said person"
article (noun):
2. A particular section or item of a series in a written document, as in a contract, constitution, or treaty.(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

Why are you using Urban Dictionary to understand things? This is a sarcastic definition, referring to an arbitrary (newspaper or blog) article that quotes a person as an authority. It has nothing to do with "articles of the constitution". Next time use a proper dictionary.

Don't use Urban dictionary for terms that aren't slang. Even then use it with extreme caution.  This definition is basically junk and should be ignored.

I’m voting to close this question because facetious definitions in Urban Dictionary are not a useful resource for learners


the article citing said person

means the same thing as

the article that cites said person

So a comma would be wrong because "citing said person" qualifies "article".
Since articles of the Constitution don't cite people, "the article" can't mean that. It refers to articles in a newspaper or journal.
For example, when the US Supreme Court was called on to decide whether Donald Trump was immune from prosecution, there were articles in newspapers, magazines, and blogs analyzing their ruling. Many of them cited the opinions of constitutional scholars.
The Urban Dictionary definition is being sarcastic when it says that this refers specifically to people whose opinions agree with those of the article writer. The normal definition of the term is a legal scholar who has focused on the Constitution.

But, "said person" has to be a "Constitutional Scholar" (just like in your Trump/US Supreme Court ruling situation the people cited in the newspaper articles were Constitutional Scholar). So this definition basically says: Constitutional scholar is someone who agrees with an author of a news article that cites a constitutional scholar. Isn't that circular logic?

It depends on the context. I can easily imagine an article in legit news like NY Times where they report opinions on both sides of a question, and all those sources will be "constitutional scholars".

Urban Dictionary is a joke website and not an actual dictionary.
The joke in the cited definition is that some authors of news articles will use the phrase "constitutional scholar" to give weight to their own arguments.
In reality the author may not be referring to a real person at all. Or if they are, the uncertainty of what makes someone a "constitutional scholar" let's almost anyone claim they are an expert.
In any case, don't take Urban Dictionary seriously.

Urban Dictionary isn't a "joke website" but offers off-beat (or on-beat street) definitions away from scholarly discourse. It has its place. It's a useful resource for the vernacular, but not for English learners.
